# Loop through changing variables

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables

I would like to find a more serious code for the one below. I am looping through a number of variables (player1, TSP1, player2, TSP2,...).
Here is the ugly code, that works fine:

```
if (TSP1 < player1) {
    $("#errornotice").html("Minimum TSP player 1 " is " + player1);
    player1-list.focus();
} else if (TSP2 < player2) {
    $("#errornotice").html("Minimum TSP player 2 " is " + player2);
    player2-list.focus();
} else if (TSP3 < player3) {
    $("#errornotice").html("Minimum TSP player 3 " is " + player3);
    player3-list.focus();
} else if (TSP4 < player4) {
    $("#errornotice").html("Minimum TSP player 4 " is " + player4);
    player4-list.focus();
}

<b><span style="color:red" id ="errornotice"></span></b><br>
```

How can I get it to do the same less ugly in a loop ?
Something like this:

```
for (var a = 1; a < 4; a++){
     if (TSP+a < speler+a) {
          $("#errornotice").html("Minimum TSP player" +a+ " is " + player+a);
          Thuisspeler1-list+a.focus();
      }
}
```

Obviously, the syntaxis is completely wrong, but that's just to give you an idea of what I would like to achieve. I am really stuck here, so all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: for (var a = 1; a < 4; a++){
     if (thuisTSP+a < speler+a) {
          $("#errornotice").html("Minimum TSP player" +a+ " is " + player+a);
          Thuisspeler1-list+a.focus();
      }
}

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand the purpose of the code snippet, so sorry if this look obvious to you,  but:

- Have you look at switch / case command?
- Have those variables to be set like that, can't you get an array instead?

Comment: alak, I have looked at those possibilities, but didn't find a solution that way either. Can you maybe illustrate how that code would look in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading this, [How to reference a variable dynamically in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834373/how-to-reference-a-variable-dynamically-in-javascript)
.

Comment: Thx Joss. But I still can't get it to work. Any idea what is still wrong here?  I added the new code in the original post.

Comment: for (var a = 1; a < 4; a++){
     if (TSP[a] < speler[a]) {
          $("#errornotice").html("Minimum TSP player" +a+ " is " + player[a]);
          Thuisspeler1-list[a].focus();
      }
}

Comment: Putting the variable between [] is not the whole solution, is it ?

Comment: You need to build an object containing the variable names and their corresponding values. You can then loop through this object like so: `myObject['string' + int]`.

Note that it's the second solution] on that page that is most relevant to you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3834401/9636451

Comment: Maybe I am asking my question the wrong way. Let me try another way. What if I wanted to alert 20 variables one after the other and their names were variable1, variable2,... Would this work in js: Code: for (var a = 1; a < 20; a++){alert(variable[a]);}

Comment: Yes, I am saying that you would need to record these variables in an object in order to do this. Unfortunately it is not possible to simply go `variable[a]` like this. You must go `for (var a=1; a<4; a++) { alert(myObject['variable' + a]) }` instead, where the object is written as: `var myObject = { variable1: 1, variable2: 2, variable3: 3, variable4: 4 }`.

Comment: Thx Joss. That's what I was looking for. Does the same go for the part of the playerlist[a].focus ? Playerlist1, playerlist2,... being inputboxes ?

Comment: Why not try it out and see? :)